# Simplify ratio of exponential functions

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

I was struggling to see how to simplify this ratio of exponentials as below:
$$\frac{\exp(-x_{i2}y - a_{i})}{\exp(-x_{i1}y - a_{i})} =  \exp((x_{i1} - x_{i2})y)$$

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{\exp x} = \exp (-x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the property that $\displaystyle \frac{e^a}{e^b}=e^{a-b}$.

Then, everything follows as such.